# iterate inside a partial view using model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently i have a view which calls partial view and everything is working fine.

Current View:

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_topposts", item)                
        }
```

Now i want to pass the model itself to the partial view instead of item inside model. Something like below

I Want Something like this:

```
            @Html.Partial("_topposts", item)
```

and then inside partial view i want this

Partial View:

```
     @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <P>Name: item.Name</p>                
        }
```

Model Class:

```
 public class PostModel
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Post { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Timeago { get; set; }
    public int CommentsCount { get; set; }

    }
   }
```

Comment: Ok so what is your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Now i want to pass the model itself`

Just use

```
@Html.Partial("_topposts", Model)
```

instead of

```
@Html.Partial("_topposts", item)
```

And your code for Partial View is good.

**Additionally** change the `@model` definition of Partial View with type of object you are passing

Comment: @Rams, Glab I could help

Answer (score 0):

You can create an action method on your controller, returning a partial view;

```
public PartialViewResult YourPartialView(int parameter)
{
    // get your viewmodel using the parameter...
    var vm = new YourPartialViewModel(parameter);
    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

In your main view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @{ Html.RenderAction("YourPartialView", new { parameter = item.id }); }
}
```

Make sure you create the partial view, that is strongly typed, of type "YourPartialViewModel"

```
@model YourPartialViewModel

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    /// .......
}
```